# Isometry of $\mathbb{R}^4$ Torus

Tags: differential-geometry

I am working on an exercise and I am stumped. The exercise is to prove that 
$$X(u,v)=(\sin u,\cos u, \sin v, \cos v)$$
is an isometry. This is in the chapter of Theorema Egregium so I assume they mean "Locally isometric" when they say that. I am also aware of that they are isometric if and only if they have the same first fundamental form.

I easily got
$$X_u=(\cos u,-\sin u, \sin v,\cos v)$$
$$X_v=(\sin u,\cos u, \cos v,-\sin v)$$
and from there
$$X_u\cdot X_u = 2$$
$$X_u\cdot X_v = 0$$
$$X_v\cdot X_v = 2$$

So far so good, for $\mathbb{R}^2$ I figured our $X$ would be $X(u,v)=(u,v)$ as a suitable one as it is fairly trivial and naturally get
$$X_u\cdot X_u = 1$$
$$X_u\cdot X_v = 0$$
$$X_v\cdot X_v = 1$$
and poof it dies. Where am I going wrong? Is this a bad tactic to take it on? Is a more direct approch better or?

Comment: There's an (obvious) mistake in your calculation...... "I easily got..."

Comment: I have been staring it for so long I am currently blind, care to point it out so I can feel stupid for a brief moment and then happy to find the solution?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \sin u \neq -\sin u$ and some others, recalculate your derivatives

Comment: Actually I just realized all eight terms in $X_u, X_v$ are calculated incorrectly.. You have to take partial derivative term by term.

Comment: OH YEAH! That is it, I forgot to make them zeros due to it. You are perfectly correct, wow thank you. Yes that WAS obvious now that it is pointed out, thank you!

Comment: Just in case you haven't found out: $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} (\sin v) = 0$..

Comment: Yes i did figure it out when you pointed out, thank you!